# iOS PFBatchFaultingArray - causing bad UITableView performance(?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I use Core Data with a NSFetchResultController in one of my apps. I'm looking for ways to improve performance, and one problem I have is with my UITableViewController. It's a bit jaggery. I've used Instruments `Time Profiler` and I found the following:

[image]

It seem to be called from the following method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [...]
    Post *cellPost = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [...]
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to solve this? Or can it be something else that is causing the performance hiccup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PFBatchFaultingArray is the kind of array you get back from executing a fetch that was configured like [`[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/setFetchBatchSize:) (or any number > 0). It acts like a regular array, but it's `-objectAtIndex:` method will actually fetch a `fetchBatchSize`-ed group of objects from disk if needed. This can be slow, but it does keep memory usage low, because only `fetchBatchSize` many objects need to actually be in memory, not `[array count]` many.

You could try configuring your fetch request with a batch size of 0, to disable this. Just be sure you can fit all the objects you need in memory.

Optimizing your app's Core Data performance may be a lot more involved than just that one change, though! There's a good overview of techniques in the
[Core Data Best Practices (2012 WWDC session)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=214).

Comment: The closing paragraph is very well written, and so is it answer :)

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I didn't specify `fetchBatchSize`, do Core Data have a default fetch size? Setting it to 0 didn't do much for the performance, but now I know what `PFBatchFaultingArray`is at least. Will take a look at the video. Thanks!